# Как узнать количество (*)

Tags: python, алгоритм, функции, print, перенос

Помогите в принте выводится через строчку звездочка, можно ли как-то убрать переносы и посчитать количество звезд[image: Условие]

Comment: Чтобы убрать переносы, достаточно прочитать хелп по print. А про звёздочки - чуть-чуть проанализировать последовательность вызовов.

Comment: не понял что нужно

Comment: код текстом в вопросе должен быть, а не фотографией. иначе вопрос будет закрыт

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы убрать переносы, используйте параметр `end=''` в функции `print`, например, `print('**', end='')`.

Чтобы посчитать звездочки, можно попробовать посмотреть порядок вызовов функций. Из кода понятно, что один вызов функции `F(n)` выводит одну звездочку, а `G(n)` две, далее отслеживаете порядок вызовов, в данном случае он такой: `F(18), F(16), F(14), F(12), F(10), G(10), F(7), G(7), F(4), G(4), F(1), G(1), F(-2), G(-2)`, отсюда легко посчитать 19 звездочек. Либо можно вручную посчитать количество звездочек в выводе.